# How to use for_each referencing to another resource in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to create a nat_gateway that allocates to all the public_subnet ids and eip nate ids however terraform is erroring

> ```
> │ aws_subnet.subnets_public is object with 3 attributes
> ```
>
> │     │ each.key is "5"

```
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "natgw" {
    for_each = {
    for i, v in var.subnets : i => v

    if v.type == "public"
  }

  allocation_id = aws_eip.nat_eip[each.key].id
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.subnets_public[each.key].id


  depends_on = [aws_internet_gateway.igw]

}
```

Comment: please share complete code, this is not chat gpt :)

Answer (score 0):

You are filtering a list in `for_each`. So that some `indexes` is missing. Then you are trying to call `aws_eip.nat_eip` with non-existing index then you are getting error.

If you can share your `var.subnets` and terraform error then we can help you to fix the error(s).